# subset-by-subset list comparison in python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of lists:

```
list1 = [[1, 2, 4], [5, 7], [9, 12]]
list2 = [[2, 1 ,4], [5, 6, 11], [9, 14, 18, 12]]
```

How can I check if all subsets of list1 are in corresponding subsets of list2 (i.e. if `[1, 2, 4]` is in `[2, 1, 4]`, `[5, 7]` in `[5, 6, 11]`, and `[9, 12]` in `[9, 14, 18, 12]`)? Order within subsets doesn't matter, but the order of subsets matters.

Subset-by-subset, the output in the example above would be True, False, True (Though I need a code that returns just one True or False, which would be False in this case).

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "subset" or "in". Can you give precise definitions? Your use of the words doesn't match standard usage.

Comment: Sure. By 'subset' in this case I mean sublist, e.g. list1 has 3 subsets here: [1, 2, 4], [5, 7] and [9, 12]. By 'in' I mean that sublist of list2 contains all elements of sublist of list1 in no particular order. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `all()` and use the `issubset` method from `set`s:

```
print all(set(e[0]).issubset(e[1]) for e in zip(list1, list2))
```

Note that `[e for e in zip(list1, list2)]` is

```
[([1, 2, 4], [2, 1, 4]), 
 ([5, 7], [5, 6, 11]), 
 ([9, 12], [9, 14, 18, 12])]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
all(set(a).issubset(b) for a, b in zip(list1, list2))
```

`set(a).issubset(b)` builds a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) out of `a` and checks whether all elements of that set are found in `b`. The generator expression `set(a).issubset(b) for a, b in zip(list1, list2)` builds an iterator that applies this to all pairs of corresponding elements of `list1` and `list2`, then `all` checks whether all the comparisons evaluate to `True`.